# mysql custom function syntax

Tags: mysql, function, syntax

hi this is my first post here. A novice web development student.
so this first function checks to see if a string contains 'cabo verde' or 'cambodia' or 'cameroon' if yes then just return the original string. otherwise if the string begins with CA regardless of upper or lower case then it returns the string 'CAN'. I think i am getting some syntax wrong as this is my first time creating custom functions in mysql.

```
DELIMITER $$
create function cleanstr( 
    string1 VARCHAR(60)
)
returns VARCHAR(60)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF(LOWER(string1) = 'cabo verde' OR LOWER(string1) = 'cambodia' OR LOWER(string1) = 'cameroon')
    THEN return string1;
    ELSE IF (REGEXP_LIKE(string1,'^ca','i') = 1)
    THEN return 'CAN';
END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

this function takes 3 integer values. if first two are null then it returns both those variables equal to  0. If the 3rd variable is NULL then it throws a 45000 error.

```
DELIMITER $$
create function ints( 
    num1 int, num2 int, num3 int
)
returns int 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF(ISNULL(num1) = 1 AND ISNULL(num2) = 1)
     THEN 
        return num1 = 0 AND num2 = 0;
    ELSE IF (ISNULL(num3) = 1)
    THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Third value is NULL';
END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I can't figure out what exactly i am missing in these functions. Hope it is something small. Thanks

Comment: "I think i am getting some syntax wrong" Please add info why you think that you are getting syntax wrong, and also info about "I can't figure out what exactly i am missing in these functions".  SO is not about guessing behavior.... 

Comment: Looking at your solution, one of the problems might be that `cleanstr('Central African Republic');` returns: `ERROR 1321 (2F005): FUNCTION cleanstr ended without RETURN`. But that is obvious based on the description you gave.

Comment: see: [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) where is says that you should not use a space between `ELSE` and `IF`.

Comment: It's unusual to be using a case sensitive collation, so first confirm that you are.